# Font replaced by default font?

Tags: java, windows, swing, fonts

I've written an application in `Swing`. For a `JLabel` I'm using a certain font (`Tekton Pro Ext`) which shows up properly on my computer. However, if someone else launches the program, the font may not be the same and then is replaced by a default one which I believe is `Arial`. Also, I'm forcing the system's default look and feel by running the following code:

```
try
{
    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
} catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException
        | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Is there a way I can fix this font issue in my application's code so that it shows for others as well? If not, how can clients assure that all fonts I can choose in `Window Builder Pro` will also work for them?

[image]

```
JLabel myLabel = new JLabel("Hello world!");
myLabel.setFont(new Font("Tekton Pro Ext", Font.BOLD, 22));
```

I haven't installed a special fonts pack but it's working on my `Windows 8.1` machine "by default" though. What could be the cause?

Comment: Start by including the font within the application Jar so you can load it at run time via `Class#getResource`; second, use `UIManager.set` to change the font used by default by the current look and feel

Comment: @MadProgrammer: How do I write a font to a `.ttf` file like the one mentioned in the question so that it can be loaded by the application?

Comment: Font files come in a variety of formats, True Type Font is just one.  What format is your `Tekton Pro Ext` font in?

Comment: @MadProgrammer: I'm not sure, I'm using the font chooser from `Window Builder Pro`. I added a picture of it to the top post

Comment: You need to track down the source font file...

Comment: @MadProgrammer: I don't know how. It doesn't get bundled

Comment: It's likely in your systems font directory...

Comment: @MadProgrammer: Yup, it's `TektonPro-BoldExt.otf`. I got it working now, thanks for being patient with me.